# Python Mongo FIlter based on Data

Tags: python, mongodb, filter, pymongo

I am trying to filter mongo data with dates.

For that I am using these sets of data:

```
def mongo_db(mydict):
    myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")
    mydb = myclient[<Db name>]
    mycol = mydb[<Collection name>]
    # mydict = {}
    x = mycol.insert_one(mydict)
    # print(x.inserted_id)
    return x.inserted_id

for i in range(1,6):
    mydict = {
    "startsAt": {
        "time": {
            "date": datetime.datetime.today() - timedelta(days = i) + timedelta(hours = i)
        },
        "valid": True
        }
    }
```

I am trying to filter certain date fro example above code generate data like:

```
"2021-02-09T13:56:09.963000Z"
"2021-02-09T13:56:09.963001Z"
```

And I want my result to be like if 2021-02-09 then filter only that.

When I am using this code:

```
filterCondition = { 
    "startsAt.time.date" : { "$lt" : datetime.datetime.today()},
    "startsAt.time.date" : { "$gt" : datetime.datetime.today() - timedelta(days=1)}
}

mycol.find(filterCondition)
```

I am getting current day:

```
"2021-02-10T00:31:47.411000Z"
```

I need to filter date yesterday and a day after yesterday only.

I have tried this format:

```
from_dt = datetime.datetime.strptime('2021-02-10','%Y-%m-%d')
#from_dts = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(from_dt)
to_dt = datetime.datetime.strptime('2021-02-08','%Y-%m-%d')
```

But no luck so I need 24 hrs full day result of yesterday. I am confused about datetime what will be yesterday?  Meaning If I have record:

```
"2021-02-09T13:56:09.963000Z"
"2021-02-09T13:56:09.963001Z"
"2021-02-09T13:56:09.963002Z"
.....
```

Then I only want this date 2021-02-09

Comment: If it's 15:00 now, you'd get anything from yesterday at 15:00 to today at 15:00, wouldn't you?
You might wan to use "_today at 00:00_" as `today`, and _`today` - 1 day_ as `yesterday`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using native BSON dates, all dates are stored as UTC; so if you want to seach from UTC 00:00 yesterday to UTC 00:00 today use:

```
today = datetime.date.today()
yesterday = datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)

start = datetime.datetime.combine(yesterday, datetime.time(0, 0)).replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc)
end = datetime.datetime.combine(today, datetime.time(0, 0)).replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc)

print(list(db.mycollection.find({'date': {'$gte': start, '$lt': end}})))
```